# Problems with DEM exporting after Elevation Void Fill function use

Tags: dem, export, nodata

I filled nodata values in DEM by Elevation Void Fill function, everything was ok, but when I exported it, the raster looks different (see picture above), how can I solve this problem? I also tried r.fillnulls in grass and Fill nodata in qgis, but Void fill function looks much better.

**before exporting**
[image]

**after exporting**
[image]